# Erlang basics: Syntax error at compile time

Tags: erlang

I am very new to Erlang and I am trying to compile my first program and I am getting a syntax error at compile time.

The syntax error I am getting points to line 2 `filter_inside` undefined. Also syntax error on last line before `X`.

functions.erl

```
-module(functions).
-export([filteri/2]).

filteri(_, []) -> 
                    []; 
filteri(P,[X|XS]) ->
                    [(map(P) X)|filteri P XS].
```

I have been trying to debug for about an hour now with no success, I was wondering if someone can help me identify what it is about the code that is making it fail to compile.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last Line  `[(map(P) X)|filter_inside P XS].`  should be `[P(X) | filter_inside(P, XS)].`
Syntax needs to be corrected. You are looking for map apply and predicate to get back the result i.e. implement `lists:map`.

Ex: `lists:map(fun(A)->A*2 end, [1,2,3,4,5]).` to get result equivalent as `[2,4,6,8,10]`

Then in Erlang you may also write like this to utilize tail recursion optimization:

```
-module(functions).
-export([filter_inside/2]).

filter_inside(P,L) ->
    filter_inside(P,L, []).

filter_inside(_, [], Acc) -> 
    lists:reverse(Acc); 
filter_inside(P,[X|XS], Acc) ->
    filter_inside(P, XS,  [P(X) | Acc]).
```

Comment: But the need to reverse the list removes a lot of the gain, see http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html#tail_recursive

Comment: I did a run for time, filter_inside2 is tail recursive `2> timer:tc(cmd,filter_inside2, [fun(A)->A*2 end,lists:seq(1,10000000)]).
{25707000,
 [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,
  44,46,48,50,52,54|...]}
3> timer:tc(cmd,filter_inside, [fun(A)->A*2 end,lists:seq(1,10000000)]).
{48666000,
 [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,
  44,46,48,50,52,54|...]}`

Comment: Also space reached around 200 MB in tail and 300 MB with body recursive function (Used crude method by looking into process memory) on 64 bit machine. Only 100 ms was faster when lists:reverse was removed and I did not see any space change.

Answer (score 4):

Erlang separates clauses by semicolons `;`.

Statements are separated by commas `,`.

Just use `[];` in the 5th line.

The last line is broken, too. To prepend an element `Head` to a list `Tail` use `[Head|Tail]` including the brackets.

A function call looks like `Fun(Arg1, Arg2, ...)`.

Erlang is case sensitive. `x` is an atom (you may see it as a string constant), whereas `X` is the variable `X`.

Easier to use than explicit recursion is list comprehension `[Fun(X) || X <- XS]` (or `[Fun(X) || X <- XS, Predicate(X)]`).

I guess you could use

```
filter_inside(Fun, XSS) ->
    [ [Fun(X) || X <- XS] || XS <- XSS ].
```

In your solution you can use this as your last line:

```
[list:map(P, X)|filter_inside(P, XS)].  % Mind the function call syntax.
```

Erlang reported a problem in the `-export` line because the function contained an error, so the name is unknown.

One further comment: Use `filter_inside(_, [])` as the last clause for speed up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still getting a syntax error before the `x` on the last line. Also in line two `export`, any suggestions?

Comment: I do not understand your intention in the last clause. `[??|filter_inside(P, XS)]`, what shall happen in the question marks? (The Erlang syntax has virtually no resemblance to Haskell. Do not try to adapt from there.)

Comment: That is exactly where I am coming from, Hasekll... I am trying to recursively apply map and Predicate P to every element of a list of lists. (Please see edited code with adjustments)

Comment: When `P` is a function just call `P(X)`. If I understand you correctly `X` is a list itself that you what to map?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wasn't looking for a new solution, my solution should work as far as logic, it is just syntax problems. I appreciate it though.

Comment: One thing you have to keep in mind when programming Erlang is that it does not use implicit currying. The syntax derived from Prolog, so you have to do function calls that resemble C's syntax: `func()`, `func(A)`, `func(A, b, 1)`.

Comment: `[ [Fun(X) || X <- XS] || XS <- XSS ]` can be written as `[ Fun(X) || XS <- XSS, X <- XS ]` which is more convenient way.